# SQL parameterised Insertion Union Query

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite, ios5, multiple-insert

I have been successful with multiple insertion with around 200 records but my problem is order in which the data is being inserted.The records are inserted in `SD_0`, `SD_1`, `SD_10`, `SD_100`, ..so on.

My required order is `SD_0`, `SD_1`, `SD_2`, `SD_3`,....so on.

Here is my Query:-

```
insert into Coffee (coffeeName,price) select ? as coffeeName ,? as price
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
 UNION SELECT ? , ?
```

Let me know if any changes are required in this query.

I am using this query with the Objective-C code.

Below I am adding the code:

-(void)addCoffee: (NSMutableDictionary *)dictParam {

```
    NSString *strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into Coffee (%@) select ? as %@",[[dictParam allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@","],[[dictParam allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]];

     //For second line of query SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
     for (int i = 1; i<[dictParam count]; i++) {
               strQuery = [strQuery stringByAppendingFormat:@" ,? as %@",[[dictParam allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]];
     }

     strQuery = [strQuery stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];

     //For another union statements
     for (int j = 1; j < [[dictParam valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dictParam allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]]] count]; j++) {

          strQuery = [strQuery stringByAppendingFormat:@"UNION SELECT ?"];

          for (int i = 1; i<[dictParam count]; i++) {

               strQuery = [strQuery stringByAppendingFormat:@" , ?"];
          }
          strQuery = [strQuery stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];

      }
      const char *sql =  [strQuery UTF8String];

      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

      int counter = 1;

      for (int j = 0; j < [[dictParam valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dictParam allKeys]       objectAtIndex:0]]] count]; j++) {

         for (int i = 0; i<[dictParam count]; i++) {

               sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, counter, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dictParam valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dictParam allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]]] objectAtIndex:j]] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

               counter++;

         }
       }
       if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
          NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
       else
          coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);


   //Reset the add statement.
   sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
```

}

Comment: Please paste your code directly into the question, rather than posting to an outside service.  Readers will probably not be able to see the external code and thus this question will be useless to them. **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**